# Html table rowspan not working correctly

Tags: html

So i've got a problem with the rowspan and i don't know how to repair it,i'm just a beginner when we are talking about tables in html

```
<body>
  <p><font size=6><b><center>ORARUL CLASEI XII-B</center></b></font></p>
  <table align=center border cellspacing=1>
    <tr>
      <th bgcolor="yellow" colspan=5>Orar</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width=250>Luni </td>
      <td width=250>Marti </td>
      <td width=250 align=center>Miercuri </td>
      <td width=250>Joi </td>
      <td width=250>Vineri</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="red">Geografie </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ADFF2F">Logica </td>
      <td bgcolor="#00AB66">Engleza </td>
      <td bgcolor="purple">Istorie </td>
      <td bgcolor="cyan" rowspan=2>Fizica </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="red">Biologie </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ADFF2F">Matematica </td>
      <td bgcolor="#00AB66">Matematica </td>
      <td bgcolor="purple" rowspan=2>Matematica </td>
      <td bgcolor="cyan">Romana </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="red">Fizica </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ADFF2F">Fizica </td>
      <td bgcolor="#00AB66">Sport </td>
      <td bgcolor="purple">Engleza </td>
      <td bgcolor="cyan">Informatica </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="red">Religie </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ADFF2F">Matematica </td>
      <td bgcolor="#00AB66">Franceza </td>
      <td bgcolor="purple">Educatie Sanatate </td>
      <td bgcolor="cyan">Franceza </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="red">Informatica </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ADFF2F" rowspan=2>Informatica </td>
      <td bgcolor="#00AB66">Dirigentie </td>
      <td bgcolor="purple">Romana </td>
      <td bgcolor="cyan">Informatica </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="red">Romana </td>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#00AB66">Chimie </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FvY5b/41/

Ty for your assistance

Comment: Note: `font` and `center` are deprecated/obsolete/removed.

Comment: Explain what the problem is.

Comment: Even jsfiddle shows that your html structure is incorrect, notice additional `</td>` at the last `<tr>`

Comment: I just want the table to be a box and the color to sit in the place that belong(purple with purple,cyan with cyan,etc..)

Comment: @Victor so why are you using rowspan? What do you want the table to look like?

Comment: i just it to look like a schedule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is how You wanted. Just misplaced the `table data's` as you used row-spans in your code you must have to be careful.

```html
<title> Tabel </title>

<body>
  <p>
    <font size=6><b><center>ORARUL CLASEI XII-B</center></b></font>
  </p>
  <table align=center border cellspacing=1>
    <tr>
      <th bgcolor="yellow" colspan=5>Orar</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width=250>Luni</td>
      <td width=250>Marti</td>
      <td width=250 align=center>Miercuri</td>
      <td width=250>Joi</td>
      <td width=250>Vineri</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="red">Geografie</td>
      <td bgcolor="#ADFF2F">Logica</td>
      <td bgcolor="#00AB66">Engleza</td>
      <td bgcolor="purple">Istorie</td>
      <td bgcolor="cyan" rowspan=2>Fizica </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="red">Biologie</td>
      <td bgcolor="#ADFF2F">Matematica</td>
      <td bgcolor="#00AB66">Matematica</td>
      <td bgcolor="purple" rowspan=2>Matematica</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="red">Fizica</td>
      <td bgcolor="#ADFF2F">Fizica</td>
      <td bgcolor="#00AB66">Sport</td>
      <td bgcolor="cyan">Informatica</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="red">Religie</td>
      <td bgcolor="#ADFF2F">Matematica</td>
      <td bgcolor="#00AB66">Franceza</td>
      <td bgcolor="purple">Engleza</td>
      <td bgcolor="cyan">Franceza</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="red">Informatica </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ADFF2F" rowspan=2>Informatica </td>
      <td bgcolor="#00AB66">Dirigentie</td>
      <td bgcolor="purple">Romana</td>
      <td bgcolor="cyan">Informatica</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="red">Romana</td>
      <td bgcolor="#00AB66">Chimie</td>
      <td bgcolor="purple">Educatie Sanatate</td>
      <td bgcolor="cyan">Romana</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
```

Comment: Accept if it does. :-)